# Axon Event Store Handling - Read All events for an aggregate

Tags: java, spring, axon, axon-framework

I am using Axon with Spring boot and will like to list an event history for an aggregate.
With the `event` `store -> readEvents(String id)`, we only get events from the last snapshot.

```
eventStore.readEvents(aggregateId).asStream().map(e -> e.getpayload()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

How can I read all the events for that aggregate since creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EventStore` interface also exposes another method:

`DomainEventStream readEvents(String aggregateIdentifier, long firstSequenceNumber)`

You can use that one with a `0` as second parameter to force the Event Store to return all events starting from sequence 0, which is the very first event for an aggregate.

Comment: Thanks @Allard it worked, I was just looking at the default method in the interface instead of the implementation class that overrides it(AbstractEventStore).